# What did I do wrong with my lotion bar that it was grainy at the bottom of the mold?

Tags: solutions

I want to create a with cocoa butter bar and coconut oil, that emulsifies quickly when rubbed in your hands. I made a tiny batch with a 6:1 ratio (6 tbsp CB and 1tbsp CO) and they have held together just fine in a variety of temperatures. (The only thing I did different with these besides the smaller ratio of coconut oil is melt both oils together instead of separately).

I went ahead and made a larger batch and tried a tad bit more coconut oil 11(oz):2.5(oz) and I got bars that were totally grainy (I assume it was the coconut oil?). Interesting, the last 5 bars of the batch were fine when I popped them out of the mold. I am assuming the coconut oil is lighter and rose to the top and was poured out first, leaving very little for the last few molds. I"m having difficulty attaching a photo to this message but I can try again.

I heated separately both the cocoa butter and coconut oil in glass measuring cups and hot water on the stove. max temp 170F for 20ish minutes ( is that too hot perhaps?).

Then I mixed the two oils together and mixed them with a blender stick for 40 seconds. Scooped bubbles off that rose to the top.

As I was making sample sized bars, I poured 5/8 oz of mixture into individual silicone molds. But outside in 32F for 15-20 minutes. Then room temp 65-69F for 24 hours.

Ingredients used:
Cocoa Butter - Unrefined, Organic
Coconut Oil - Virgin, Cold pressed, Organic

Questions:
Should I use less coconut oil? I am looking for a bar that emulsifies quickly in your hand that is not too sticky.

If not coconut oil, might another natural product help soften the cocoa butter to that end?

Am I heating the oils too high or too long?

Is there a way to cure the bars successfully?Make sure there are no tiny bubbles in the mold?

Thank you so much for your time and expertise.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the cooking stack exchange